# Github workflow for multiple environments for continuous delivery system

Tags: git, github, azure-devops

How to do the partial merge from one branch to another branch with GitHub for Azure DevOps CI/CD?

I am really new to Github and Azure DevOps. I have just started learning CI/CD with Azure DevOps and built some pipeline with GitHub as a project source.

Can you help me out the workflow of how we should manage it for CI?

I have two environments - one is the development and the other one is live. Each has their branch for example master for live and development for a development environment. Two developers are involved to make changes like feature A and feature B. So after completing their work they committed and merge their changes to the development branch which gets deployed automatically using the CI/CD pipeline.

In the development environment, a tester tested the code and found Feature B is not working the way it should. And do an OK to Feature A.

Now we want to deploy the code related to Feature A only to the master branch. What should be the workflow for that? How can we do a merge to the master branch?

PS: CI trigger for every commit takes place on any branch. Commit id is associated with work id in the Azure board.

Comment: Are feature A and feature B two different branches?

Comment: no feature A and feature B is a work that will accomplish a task for example feature A might create a page and feature B create another page. When work finishes they will eventually merge with the master branch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft's documentation on [branching strategy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/git-branching-guidance?view=azure-devops) is well worth a read, the main point is to keep things as simple as possible.

If you're using [multi-stage pipelines](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/azure-devops-pipelines-multi-stage-pipelines-and-yaml-for-continuous-delivery/) where your build (CI) and release (CD) stages are defined in yaml code as one pipeline, then this encourages you to build and deploy your code from one branch.

If it really is 2 developers and just 2 features developing / being worked on at the same time, I'd say the development branch is overkill, and just master and feature branches would suffice.  The idea being that feature A gets merged to master and goes all the way through your pipeline to your live environment, before feature B gets merged.  In hopefully the rare cases that master breaks then it's "stop the line" and everyone works to fix master before any further features are merged.

If you feel uneasy about potentially breaking master and the only way to raise the confidence of not doing so is a physical deployment to an environment, you might investigate application architectures that make it both timely and cost effective to spin up and down environments based on a feature branch (e.g. Containerisation ([AKS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/)) or Serverless ([Azure Functions](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/functions))) and / or introducing an integration test suite that runs at build time.

Most pipelines push the same built artifacts from one environment to the next to minimize risk, this is particularly the practice in with .net applications (a package of DLLs etc).  The problem in the scenario you describe is if you cherry pick commits for feature A, and then building that, you're going to be pushing a new untested version of the application to production.  You don't know if you made a mistake with the cherry pick or worse still, things in feature B allowed feature A to work.  The simplest solution is pushing smaller changes more frequently all the way through your pipeline to production (continuous delivery).

Best of luck with the project!

Comment: Actually the main problem which I am facing is how to isolate code from different developers as they can be more in future. Earlier what we used to do whenever any work item got passed by Qa team we get the changesets from that story or workitem and merge them to staging branch. But with github if I do the same thing for example use commit ids and do those commits I am not fully sure that approach will work. I have also see cherry pick command of github but not sure that will be right way. Or should developers do a pull after every commit and then I wil just use those pulls to merge it?

Comment: Hi @prashant, I've updated my answer with reasons why cherry picking would introduce risk.  I'd say pull requests of sets of commits, either a complete feature or an easy to review piece of code that won't impact the application running is the way to go. 
Pushing each change individually may sound like it would slow you down, but focusing on getting it to production with as much automation (deployment and testing) as possible solves this, and from experience out weighs the time spent preparing for and fixing issues when pushing lots of different changes at once.

Comment: I started to understand this. If I focus on features rather than individual task then it will be easier to do things. So if feature A needs to create a login page and feature B creates a signup page. I will just wait for both the tasks to complete and get a sign off for both features from QA and then push that to another environment.  So that both stories get testing first and the impact can also be tested before moving to another environment.

Comment: And also with your comment If I were to push small changes, it needs to merge from a branch only not by cherry-picking or pull request. So the workflow will be like If both the developers do a commit on development and feature A get passed by QA but feature B doesn't pass then we can either ask Developer B( responsible for Feature B) to turn off the code by using a flag or undo its changes if it is affecting the current build and move feature A code from developer branch to Master branch?

Comment: Small changes using pull requests are preferable to ensure a code review takes place, completing the pull request merges the change into the target branch.  Your strategy for dealing with two concurrent features sounds good!

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your discussion really helped me a lot. I will mark as solved 